# How can I import modules in python?

Tags: python-3.x, module, pyautogui

I downloaded pyautogui from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAutoGUI) but it will not let me import it or use any functions it allows a new python file, even though I have run the setup file in that file **and** have written

```
pip install pyautogui
```

and

```
import pyautogui
```

and

```
import module pyautogui
```

In the python IDLE module.

I am doing this in python 3.4.2 and am just getting returned with errors saying that it is not found.

**Edit:**

```
Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:15:05) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> pip install pyautogui
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

The word "install" is highlighted in red

Comment: What OS are you running? The page you linked says OS X and Linux systems have additional dependencies which you would need to install.

Comment: Windows 10 Operating system.

Comment: Ok, guessing it is a path configuration issue then. What is your path and the install location of pyautogui? And just to be sure, the exact error you're getting? (for instance, `import module pyautogui` should just give you a SyntaxError.)

Comment: It is a syntax error and pyautogui is in the downloads folder (ThisPC\Downloads) and was extracted (unzipped) to the desktop

Comment: I meant the exact error message. You have to run `pip install pyautogui` in the terminal, not in IDLE. Did you do that? If no, try that. If yes, what is the output of `import pyautogui` and output of `import sys, print(sys.path)`? This might be long so please [edit] and add to your original post instead of putting in comments.

Comment: Revisiting my old activity - hopefully you've figured it out by now, but in the edit it appears you were typing `pip install pyautogui` in a *python terminal*, not an actual terminal. `pip` is a program and must be run separately from the command line (in Windows, "cmd").

Answer (score 1):

try this code for installing pyautogui using Python:-

```
import os
os.system("pip install pyautogui")
```

And then try to import library